# How do I prevent gaps while selecting by hour in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I have the current SQL query to select requests per hour:

```
SELECT ((FLOOR( unix_timestamp(request_when)/(60*60))*(60*60))*1000) as request_when, COUNT(*) as amount 
FROM api_requests WHERE request_when BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY HOUR(request_when) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

**The problem** is that when there are 0 rows it just doesn't return a row, which is expected based on the query. However, I would like it to return 0 (with the correct datetime/timestamp). I have played around with other queries but none of them seem to work.

An example output of what happens now is:

```
1289516400000   6
1289512800000   15
1289509200000   11
1289505600000   31
1289476800000   3
```

You will notice it skipped a few hours. If you don't feel like doing the math, the datetime values of those timestamps are

```
2010-11-11 12:00:00 3
2010-11-11 20:00:00 31
2010-11-11 21:00:00 11
2010-11-11 22:00:00 15
2010-11-11 23:00:00 7
```

I would like the times without rows (hours 13-19, for example) to return "0" instead of no row. This would make my wanted output to look like this:

```
2010-11-11 12:00:00 3
2010-11-11 13:00:00 0
2010-11-11 14:00:00 0
2010-11-11 15:00:00 0
2010-11-11 16:00:00 0
2010-11-11 17:00:00 0
2010-11-11 18:00:00 0
2010-11-11 19:00:00 0
2010-11-11 20:00:00 31
2010-11-11 21:00:00 11
2010-11-11 22:00:00 15
2010-11-11 23:00:00 7
```

---

I went ahead and created a "helper" or "filler" table with the hours from 00 thru 23, and I tried using a RIGHT JOIN to it, but my query returns 0 rows and doesn't work at all. 
This query that doesn't work looks like this:

```
SELECT ((FLOOR( unix_timestamp(request_when)/(60*60))*(60*60))*1000) as request_when, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) as amount 
FROM api_requests RIGHT JOIN _filler ON (HOUR(api_requests.`request_when`) = _filler.`hours`)
WHERE request_when BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() GROUP BY HOUR(request_when) ORDER BY api_requests.id DESC;
```

Comment: Samples data and expected values?

Comment: Added expected values and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Select on the values in your filler table instead of the data table.  I would rephrase it as

```
select ... from  _filler left join api_requests ...
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` Works here, grouping by `_filler.hours`

Comment: I'm trying this: SELECT ... FROM _filler LEFT JOIN api_requests ON (HOUR(api_requests.`request_when`) = HOUR(_filler.`hours`))
WHERE (api_requests.request_when BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW()) GROUP BY HOUR(_filler.hours) ORDER BY api_requests.id DESC;

Comment: As an FYI, the hours column is 0000-00-00 02:00:00 as an example. no dates